# Как задать UNIQUE ключ для поля, в котором уже есть одинаковые значения (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, индексы

Вопрос в том что есть большая таблица в ней поле (int) в котором уже есть одинаковые значения. Как наложить на него уникальный ключ, чтобы  SQL больше одинаковые значения не пропускала , а  те что были в базе остались?

Я знаю что как то можно ручками. Запросом.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Чтобы создать уникальный ключ данные, по которым создается этот ключ, должны быть уникальными

Comment: А триггером это можно сделать? Триггер может отклонить вставку новых записей?

Comment: @maestro триггером можно. Для отклонения из триггера нужно поднять исключение